# How to connect Node.js and Android as Client?

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, http

Hey I just started learning how to code android apps (java) and I was wondering how to connect the app as a client-side to a server-side language specifically node.js. I am trying to use it for login, and pulling images and what not from a public directory folder...

I heard sockets and I have heard https... not sure how either of those work exactly or documents to support them.

Any answers would be great.

To make it clear I know how to use Node.js, and starting to understand Android, but I want to be able to use Node.js as my server side of things and have the android app send requests and responses to my node.js code... how do I go about that? (I used socket.io in the past, and ajax, but not sure if ajax can be used since it is not javascript...)

Answer (score 0):

Create a REST API using a Node.JS library like [ExpressJS](http://expressjs.com). I strongly advice you to use a HTTP client library to access your REST API, a good choice is [OkHttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/).